# Dynamically create the configmap yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Background : I have close to 15 *.properties files in different location. I need to create configmap for each properties files.

Currently I am manually creating configmap yaml files using

```
 kubectl create configmap app-properties --from-file= /path/app.properties.
```

Mount and everything thing is working fine.

Requirement : As soon we add any new key/value to properties file, it should get reflected in configmap yaml file. Can I dynamically create configmap yaml using some "include files".

Answer (score 2):

You could watch the properties files for modifications and recreate the ConfigMap whenever they change.

To do so, there are different tools for macOS and Linux.

### Linux

On Linux, you can watch files for changes with `inotifywait`. You could do something along the following lines:

Create the file `monitor.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
inotifywait -m -e modify "$FILE" |
  while read; do
    kubectl create configmap "$(basename $FILE)" --from-file="$FILE" --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
  done
```

Then execute it for each properties file:

```sh
./monitor.sh /path/app.properties
```

This will generate an updated ConfigMap YAML manifest with `kubectl create` and apply it with `kubectl apply` every time the `/path/app.properties` file is modified.

You can install `inotifywait` with:

```sh
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

### macOS

On macOS, you can use `fswatch` to watch for file modifications.

Create the file `monitor.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
fswatch "$FILE" |
  while read; do
    kubectl create configmap "$(basename $FILE)" --from-file="$FILE" --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
  done
```

Then execute it for each properties file:

```sh
./monitor.sh /path/app.properties
```

This will generate an updated ConfigMap YAML manifest with `kubectl create` and apply it with `kubectl apply` every time the `/path/app.properties` file is modified.

You can install `fswatch` with:

```sh
brew install fswatch
```

### Note

`fswatch` might also be available on Linux (`sudo apt-get install fswatch`), in which case you can use the `monitor.sh` script for macOS on Linux too. However, you might need to use `fswatch -o` (with the `-o` option) to ensure only a single output line.

Comment: Thanks. Can we achieve this  using jenkins pipeline.

Comment: If you want to do it in CI/CD, you probably don't need to watch for file changes, but you can just check if the file changed when the pipeline runs.

Comment: @weibeld I think there is an issue with your solution. It will create the configmap but it will give an error when running it for second time when updating it stating that it already exists.

Comment: @DawidKruk That's true, I just updated the solution so that the existing ConfigMap is updated rather than trying to create a new one.